# Replication factor in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, replication-factor

I am newbie to cassandra.
What exactly replication factor in cassandra means? 
For example,
I have 3 node cluster(node1,node2,node3) and If I create keyspace with replication factor 1,and insert data through node1,Can I read the data from other 2 nodes?
Or It will store the data in node1. Is data available in other 2 nodes for read/write operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total number of replicas across the cluster is referred to as the replication factor. A replication factor of 1 means that there is only one copy of each row on one node. You should be able to read/write data from the other two nodes, depending on ports and firewalls between nodes.